# iOS 9 displays incorrect tint color for navbar buttons on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9

Code:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.pantone320C() // bar color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // button color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()] // text color
```

How it looks on iPad Air iOS 9.0:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25vGgRxmgU_dXdhdk5FYURiTmc/view?usp=sharing

I've tested on iPhone 6 iOS 9, iPhone 5 iOS 8.0 & 8.4, iPad 3 iOS 8.4 and they all displayed correct white tint color.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I'm running up against what appears to be the same issue, in that it's IOS9 and iPad only where the tint color isn't being respected on some items. Kicking the view that contains my affected items helped. Though I'm changing it to exactly the value that is currently is.

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view viewWithTag:99699].tintColor = nil;
        [self.view viewWithTag:99699].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    });
}
```

In my case I've got UIButtons that are inside a view controller that's inside a UINavigationController inside a UIPopOverController. Looking at the viewdebugger, I could see that the buttons were incorrectly resolving tintColor. tintColor is one of the inspectable properties.

I could either set the button's tint color and clear it or do what I did above. Changes did not work unless I deferred the change.

So for you, you might try twiddling the tint color of the proxy or the navbar.